# Show that a $C^1$ solution cannot exist in a large time interval: $u_t + uu_x = 0$, $t \geq 0$ and $x \in \mathbb R$. $u(x,0)=f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Show that a $C^1$ solution of the following equation cannot exist in a large time interval: $u_t + uu_x = 0$, $t \geq 0$ and $x \in \mathbb R$. $u(x,0)=f(x)$, $x \in \mathbb R$. Here $f$ is a test function on $\mathbb R$.
Using the characteristic method, we can obtain $u=f(x-tu)$. It seems to me that if we let $t \rightarrow \infty$, we can have $u=0$, but I'm not sure whether this is the right track.

Comment: $u=f(x-tu)$ is not correct because the velocity varies along the trajectory. The characteristic equation looks like $\frac{dx}{dt}=u(t,x(t))$ so you cannot simply integrate both sides to solve it. You can of course integrate both sides to get $x(t)-x(0)=\int_0^t u(s,x(s)) ds$ but both sides still involve $x$ so the problem has not been solved.

Comment: Also, something must be said about $f$, because if $f$ is constant then it is obvious that a solution exists for all times.

Comment: @Ian The only thing about $f$ is it's smooth with compact support as stated in the problem. I will solve it again using the characteristic method.

Comment: I don't think you can actually explicitly solve this problem. I think you will need to argue implicitly that the characteristics will intersect. Anyway, merely assuming $f \in C^\infty_c$ is not good enough because $0 \in C^\infty_c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Assuming $f$ is not identically zero, there exists a point where $f'(x_0)<0.$ This is because $f$ is smooth and compactly supported. Now you need to show that the characteristic lines at such points will give the impossibility of a well-defined $u$, in a neighborhood of $x_0.$

On the contrary,  one can show that $u$ is well-defined when $f$ is either constant or non-decreasing.

Comment: Note that there is a great intuition for this: this is a system in which a small group moves faster the more members are in it. Nothing can pass through anything else, so if you have a slow (i.e. small) group in front of a fast (i.e. big) group then eventually the fast group is forced to abruptly slow down, leading to the formation of a shock. Otherwise, the fast group can just go further and further away from the slow group without creating problems. This is more or less the same as the classic traffic flow model $u_t+(1-u)u_x=0$ (in which dense traffic slows things down).

Comment: @ian,  I am more or less aware of the intuition. It is also possible to prove it rigoriously by expressing $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ in terms of $f'(\epsilon)$ and deducing that the eventual negativity of $f'$ forces $$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$ to blow up. I intended to give this as a hint.